# How to show username in the url route in Kohana PHP Framework?

Tags: php, routes, kohana, kohana-3

I am working on Kohana PHP framework.

I want to show a 'username' instead of controller name in my URL.

For example,

username = james then how to show

http://localhost:3000/james

instead of

http://localhost:3000/scrapbook/index => ... localhost:3000/scrapbook

(controller: scrapbook, action: index)

in the url.

My bootstrap file have the entry for such types of url. If I manually write ..//localhost:3000/james, it takes me to the requested page.

```
//Viewing a user's profile or account details - user/action
Route::set('profile', '(<username>(/<action>(/<id>)))',
    array(
        'username'   => '([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'scrapbook',
        'action'     => 'index'));
```

What I want is if I manually signin and go to scrapbook, my url should show 'username' and not the name of the controller. I will appreciate if anyone can guide me in this.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just asking, because normally this should be documented in the kohana framework. That's called routing if it helps: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing

Comment: I have the routing shown below. But when I manually login by james userid, i want to show james in the URL. I havent started anything on this. THinking what I should change so that it will replace my scrapbook controller with the username...                        //Viewing a user's profile or account details - user/action
 Route::set('profile', '(<username>(/<action>(/<id>)))',
  array(
   'username'   => '([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)'))
  ->defaults(array(
   'controller' => 'scrapbook',
   'action'     => 'index'));

Comment: I did pasted in the question since i cannot answer my own question. Thanks

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your problem is more on generating the custom URL to be put in the `<a href="">` rather than making Kohana understand the custom URL. How do you generate the URL? Do you use `URL::base()` or `Route::uri()`?

Comment: Hi Lukman, I am new to this framework. As far as I know, i m setting up the URL in the bootstrap.php as shown above. Can you please let me know, how can I check the way I am creating the URL?

Answer (score 3):

When you complete your sign in action, you'll want to redirect the user to the desired URL using reverse routing:

```
// ...in your controller
function action_signin()
{
    // ...sign in logic

    $this->request->redirect(
        Route::get('profile')->uri(array(
            'username' => $username
        ))
    );
}
```

`$username` will be whatever the username of the user of the logged in user is that just signed in.

Comment: Hi david, I tried above code into my scrapbook controller when user actually sign in, but it still shows localhost/XYZ/scrapbook and not replacing 'scrapbook' word by the name of the 'username'. I need to show user their username in the URL like twitter or other websites shows.

Comment: Can you paste in your code for what happens after someone signs in and you redirect them? Also, has the route that you included in your question changed at all?

Comment: Hi David, sorry for the late reply. It worked. My routing was correct, but I was messing at some other place. I used the same routing as shown in my question.